# BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, ads

```
W/flutter (29884): onAdFailedToLoad: 3
I/Ads     (29884): Ad failed to load : 3
I/flutter (29884): BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad
```

I made a firebase account and I connect to a flutter app, but something goes wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: Will you answer this question? without any context how can someone help you? Welcome to SO. Please read [MCVE] provide context to question, what have you tried? what error you getting? steps to reproduce issue etc etc..

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are making common mistake with the Ad Unit ID. Check that you are not using thesame **APP ID** as **AD UNIT ID**

AD UNIT ID looks like `ca-app-pub-504515xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx` (what you should use for ad unit),
while APP ID looks like `ca-app-pub-504515xxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxx` - It's for the App ID and not for AD UNIT ID. you need the one separated by `/`

Solution Code:

```
BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
  // Replace the testAdUnitId with an ad unit id from the AdMob dash.
  // https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
  // https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads
  //  adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
  adUnitId: "ca-app-pub-504515xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx", // look out for this
  size: AdSize.smartBanner,
  targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
  listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
    print("BannerAd event is $event");
  },
);
```